# How to inverse z complex transform?

Tags: partial-fractions, z-transform

I have this z transform
$$32(\frac{z(z+\frac{3}{8})}{(z-z_{1})(z-\overline{z}_{1})})$$
with
$$z_{1}=\frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{4}i$$
The problem is I am not sure how to perform a partial fraction on these, maybe a property with the conjugated ?

I should have it on form of
$$32(A\frac{z}{z-z_{1}} + \overline{A}\frac{z}{z-\overline{z}_{1}})$$
What can be the value of $A$?

I think it is $\frac12+\frac7{32}i$ but I am not sure
solved, is $\frac12+\frac7{8}i$

Comment: Don't use `*` for multiplication. Multiplication is implied by terms that are bunched together.

Comment: Why don't you just sub in the values of $z_1$, $\bar{z_1}$ and your presumed value of $A$ and evaluate it to see if you end up with the original transform?

Comment: because even if is right, i don't know how to get there. I have the value from an old photo, not sure if is right or the method used

Comment: Well if you want to know whether it's right, my suggestion stands. To actually _get_ there, consider that what you have is really just a rational expression in $z$ with the degree of the numerator equalling that of the denominator, so a simple scalar value for $A$ makes sense. Do you know how to do polynomial division?

Comment: well did and the answer is 1/2+7/8 i

Comment: Nice! Well done man :)